# Error selecting all active cells in a sheet

Tags: excel, vba

Haven't done any programming in 10 years and are now trying to automate some administrative work. I need to create a CSV file from a certain data set.
Running below code stand alone using this code to select the range:

```
Set rng = Sheets("HAOD").Range("A2", Cells(Range("a1000000").End(xlUp).row, Range("xfd1").End(xlToLeft).Column))
```

works fine but if I call the sub from my main program I get error 1004 and the debugger points to my range selection. I tried using this code for the range selection instead, I use this in a VBA vlookup function I found online and it works perfectly there:

```
rng = .Range("A2:" & tblEnd & .Cells(.Rows.Count, tblEnd).End(xlUp).row).Value
```

But when using this it first complains about the .-reference and when I add `Sheets("HAOD")` I get the 1004 error again. This time even when running the sub stand alone. What am I doing wrong?

```
Sub CreateCheckITfile()

    Call PopulateHAODtab
    Call SaveAsCSV

End Sub

Sub SaveAsCSV()

Dim myFile As String
Dim rng As Range
Dim cellValue As Variant
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer

myFile = Application.DefaultFilePath & "\HAOD.csv"

Set rng = Sheets("HAOD").Range("A2", Cells(Range("a1000000").End(xlUp).row, Range("xfd1").End(xlToLeft).Column))

Open myFile For Output Lock Write As #1

For i = 1 To rng.Rows.Count
    Dim fileRow As String
    fileRow = ""
    For j = 1 To rng.Columns.Count
        cellValue = rng.Cells(i, j).Value

        If j = rng.Columns.Count Then
            fileRow = fileRow & cellValue
            Print #1, fileRow
        Else
            fileRow = fileRow & cellValue & ","
        End If
    Next j
Next i

Close #1
End Sub
```

Comment: Use of dots implies a With statement `With Sheets("HAOD")` Your `rng definition doesn't look right, you have three ranges in there?

Answer (score 1):

All references need to specify the sheet, otherwise they default to the active sheet

```
 Set rng = Sheets("HAOD").Range("A2",  Sheets("HAOD").Cells( Sheets("HAOD").Range("a1000000").End(xlUp).row,  Sheets("HAOD").Range("xfd1").End(xlToLeft).Column))
```

Comment: Thanks that did it but when I try to do the same thing to the much prettier `Set rng = Sheets("HAOD").Range("A2:" & tblEnd & Sheets("HAOD").Cells(Sheets("HAOD").Rows.Count, tblEnd).End(xlUp).row).Value` I still get the 1004 error

Comment: What's the actual value of `tblEnd`?

Comment: Damn I missed that it should be "L". Adding that instead gives error 424: Object required error.
I'm just trying to find a way to select all active cells in the sheet. Must be some smart way to do it that doesn't require giving the last column etc

Comment: Well you could use Set rng = sheets("HADD").usedrange  but that is everything from A1 to where ever control -End takes you so you might want to check that before using it

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I prefer to do it in little steps that way it lets me step through and see if everything is working as intended. This is kind of similar to the second version of what you tried, but I thought it would be more clear if the `address` property was used instead of `tblend`. Using a `With` block also helps keep it looking tidier.

Try replacing your `set` statement with this:

```
With Sheets("HAOD")
    lastrow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    lastcol = .Cells.Find("*", searchorder:=xlByColumns, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Column
    Set Rng = .Range("A2:" & .Cells(lastrow, lastcol).Address)
End With
```

Comment: Thanks Broato! Very neat and it works like a charm. Thanks to everyone supporting! Appreciate it greatly.